# Export file does not work in IE 11

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, export

I'm trying to export an Excel file, so far it does work for browsers except IE 11. Following is the code I have :

```
if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {

        myFrame.document.open("text/html", "replace");
        myFrame.document.write(data);
        myFrame.document.close();
        myFrame.focus();
        myFrame.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName);
    } else {
        var blobdata = new Blob(data], { type: 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel' });
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", window.URL.createObjectURL(blobdata));
        link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
    }
```

There is no error message in IE 11, just nothing happened. It works fine for IE < 11.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think navigator.appname is what you want,
from : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_appname.asp
The returned value varies from different browsers:
IE11, Firefox, Chrome and Safari returns "Netscape"
IE 10 and earlier versions return "Microsoft Internet Explorer"
Opera returns "Opera"

You might consider using navigator.userAgent 
and make sure that you are parsing the string properly.

Comment: Thanks, what a careless way I did